# Setting MonoTouch.Dialog UITableView position?

Tags: xamarin.ios, monotouch.dialog

Is there a way to set the position of a MonoTouch.Dialog DialogViewController?  I have subclassed DialogViewController and added a UIToolbar at the top and now I want to shift the table view down the corresponding pixels.

```
public class MyViewController : DialogViewController
{
    UIToolbar toolbar;

    public SessionsListViewController (RootElement rootElement) : base(rootElement)
    {
      this.toolbar = new UIToolbar(new RectangleF(0,0,768,44));
      this.toolbar.Items = new UIBarButtonItem[0];
      this.Add(toolbar);
    }
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9763196/monotouch-dialog-add-a-toolbar-at-the-bottom-of-the-dialog

I've tested this and it works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was never able to change the position of the TableView in the MonoTouch.Dialog. It's not a problem of the library though, its how the TableViewController works, which is inherited by MT.Dialog.

The TableViewController class is supposed to manage the positioning of the TableView automatically, and you're not supposed to work around that. Even if you create the TableView with a different position, like miguel.de.icaza mentioned about, the TableViewController will rearrange the TableView during the WillAppear method.

When not using MT.Dialog, the best way to work aound this, and to for example, have a table on just half of the screen is to drop the TableViewController and simply use a UIViewController with a TableView object. You can still pass the delegate and datasource to the TableView, so effectively you just loose the automatic positioning of the TableView.

I tried to change MT.Dialog to inherit from UIViewController instead of UITableViewController, but that caused lots of problems and I was never able to finish it. Maybe someday I'll do it.

I would love to hear I'm wrong about this though!

Answer (score 1):

In order to get around a similar issue, I changed the derivation chain of DialogViewController to inherit UIViewController and create the UITableView directlyinstead.  This allowed me to use a bitmap as the background and the only way to do that is to change things around a bit.  I plan on checking this into the source tree we any other updates and code clean up, but need to clean a number of the interfaces up instead

Comment: Kenny, did you ever complete this work?  It sounds exactly like something I could use... unless there's a better way to add a UIToolbar to a MonoTouch.Dialog...

Answer (score -1):

Just override the MakeTableView method in MyViewController, the default implementation is:

```
return new UITableView (bounds, style)
```

So all you have to do is change the bounds passed.

Comment: Thanks Miguel.  I tried both of the methods below, and the table view is not changing position at all.  I'm hitting the breakpoint, so I know it's getting called, but no matter what values I pass in, the table is not moving.


    public override UITableView MakeTableView (RectangleF bounds, UITableViewStyle style)
    {
        var newBounds = new RectangleF(500, 500 , 10, 10);
        //return base.MakeTableView (newBounds, style);
        return new UITableView(newBounds, style);
    }