# MonoTouch Dialog add a toolbar at the bottom of the dialog

Tags: xamarin.ios, uitoolbar, monotouch.dialog

I am trying to add a Toolbar that is anchored to the bottom of a MonoTouch Dialog.

Here is an example:

[image]

So as you scroll, the table's contents scroll but the toolbar at the bottom remains in view always. I know how to do this by using the interface builder, but no clue as to how to do this with Mt.D. Please please tell me it can be done!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To do this, it's probably easiest to use the DialogViewController and its View as a child of another UIViewController.

Just create your `public class MyViewController : UIViewController` class and then create and size your child views in the `override ViewDidLoad` method.